# How to update gobuffalo models with pop?

Tags: buffalo

I'm starting a project and already check how useful is gobuffalo/pop.
I have never previously used a framework for my GO projects. I just used the `stdlib` and I'm used to working with Django too.

In Django it is pretty straight forward to create/update a model and generate its migrations. It gets the current DjangoModel and generates a migration with the changes. What a surprise to me when I can't find how to do it with pop.

I already checked the documentation but I couldn't find any examples.

How do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you can only generate empty migrations and write them yourself: https://gobuffalo.io/en/docs/db/migrations#writing-migrations

There's an issue asking to implement a Django-like migrations generator (https://github.com/gobuffalo/pop/issues/184), but it's not done yet and requires a lot of work.